Understanding the charging and discharging of a capacitor using two LEDs
Here is a circuit from the book Electronics for Dummies:

I try to understand how this circuits works.
Why LED1 is light briefly when capacitor is charged and why is go off after x time and why LED2 is light up when switch is change position and capacitor is discharge?

I'd recommend building this circuit in falstad circuit simulator.  It is a browser based simulator that will let you visually see the changes in voltage and current in the circuit.  It is great for building an intuition on how circuits work!

Basic idea

This circuit enables you to watch a capacitor charging and discharging.

To measure the current in a circuit, we usually insert a resistor, and measure the voltage drop across it.  However, it varies and an error occurs. If we insert an LED instead of a resistor to visualize the current, the voltage drop will hardly vary and the error decreases. The reason is that the LED behaves like a dynamic resistor that changes its resistance opposite to current changes.
Implementation
The circuit consists of three parts:

input voltage source implemented by an SPDT switch,

RC differentiating circuit,

bipolar LED indicator (LED1 and LED2 contrary back to back).


LEDs serve as a visual indicator (ammeter) of current flow. So, this is an RC circuit with visualized current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
We can explore it in a more classical way using the CircuitLab Time-Domain simulation.



Equivalent circuits
However, I suggest we delve even deeper by examining the circuit with a DC simulation at three typical time points. To achieve this, we can replace the capacitors with voltage sources (rechargeable batteries B) with the corresponding voltage for the considered time point. Also, to observe the current, we can replace the resistor with an ammeter with the same 1 kΩ internal resistance. Another simplification is that I have used rounded decimal values for the quantities.
Charging the capacitor

Why LED1 is light briefly when capacitor is charged...

To start, let's set the switch to the "charging" position so the input voltage with a jump becomes maximum (10 V).
Vc = 0 V: The capacitor (battery B), however, is not charged and its voltage is zero. Only the input voltage acts in the circuit and the current is maximum: I = (Vin - Vb - Vled)/R = (Vin - Vled)/R = 9/1 = 9 mA (1 V is dropped across the LED1).

simulate this circuit
From Vin's perspective, the capacitor represents a short circuit (a piece of wire).

simulate this circuit
Vc = 5 V: The capacitor (B) begins to charge and the voltage across it increases; at some point, it reaches 5 V. It is a voltage source connected in the opposite direction to the input source. Its voltage is subtracted from the input voltage and "weakens" the input source; as a result, the current decreases almost twice. Figuratively speaking, the capacitor is an "ungrateful source" because the input source creates it, but in "gratitude" it opposes it and interferes with it :-)

simulate this circuit

... and why is go off after x time?

Vc = 10 V: Eventually, the capacitor charges up to (nearly) 10 V, effectively canceling out the input source. No current flows, causing LED1 to turn off.

simulate this circuit
Now Vin "thinks" that the circuit is open.

simulate this circuit
Discharging the capacitor

... and why LED2 is light up when switch is change position and capacitor is discharge?

Then, let's set the switch to the "discharging" position so the input voltage with a jump returns to zero.
Vc = 10 V: Until this point, the two voltage sources were perfectly balanced, and there was no voltage in the circuit. Now, Vin disappears, and only Vc remains active. The current reverses its direction and is maximum: I = (Vc - Vin - Vled)/R = (Vc - Vled)/R = 9/1 = 9 mA (1 V is dropped across the LED2).

simulate this circuit
Vc = 5 V: The capacitor begins to discharge and the voltage across it gradually decreases; at some point, it reaches 5 V. As a result, the current decreases almost twice.

simulate this circuit
Vc = 0 V: Eventually, the capacitor completely discharges, and the current stops flowing. LED2 goes out completely.

simulate this circuit
Imperfections
But the (1 V) voltage drop across the LEDs decreases the current. Look at the graphs for Schematic 1. Do you notice that the peak charging current is not 10 mA but 9 mA? This is because 1 V of the input voltage is lost across LED1. Then, do you notice that the discharge current is neither 10 mA nor 9 mA but 8 mA? This is because from the 9 V charging voltage, another 1 V is lost across LED2 during the discharging.
Improvement
Can we compensate for these losses to obtain an ideal LED ammeter?
Conceptual circuit
The solution is obvious: we need to add 1 V of voltage to each of the LEDs to compensate for the 1 V loss. Thus, the LEDs and the compensating voltage sources form an "ideal LED ammeter" with zero voltage drop across it.

simulate this circuit
The result is amazing: both the charging and discharging currents are exactly 10 mA!


Op-amp circuit
In practice, the role of the compensating sources is played by an op-amp. It adjusts its output voltage Voa to be equal to the voltage drop Vled across the LED. As a result, the total voltage Voa + Vled is zero (virtual ground).

simulate this circuit
The result is the same as above.


Conclusions

An LED inserted in a circuit does not impede current variations because it changes its "resistance" opposite to current changes thus keeping a constant voltage.
The undesired voltage drop across an LED can be compensated by an equal voltage to obtain an "ideal LED ammeter".
The compensating voltage can be produced by an op-amp; as a result, a virtual ground appears at its inverting input.


Follow the current flow.  Conventional current flow is that current flows from the most positive node to the most negative node.  Also note that the capacitor RESISTS changes in voltage.
When the switch is moved from the Discharge position to the Charge position, the capacitor is initially discharged.  Because it resists changes in voltage, it initially appears to be a short circuit.  Thus, LED1 illuminates.  Now the capacitor begins to charge.  As it charges, the LED becomes more and more dim until it goes out.
Now move the switch to the Discharge position.  The capacitor has voltage across it - about the battery voltage minus the forward voltage of LED1.  Recall that I said that current flows from the most positive node to the most negative node.  Thus: LED2 illuminates, then fades to nothing after a time period.
The time period is set by the amount of capacitance and the resistor value.

when the capacitor is charged and led 1 is lights it means it must have a 9v on is anode pin right? how does it possible if no current pass between the capacitor leads?

When the capacitor is fully discharged, it has 0V across it. Initially then, the capacitor has zero volts across it, and the switch is at position 1:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
KCL tells us current \$I\$ is the same at all points around the loop, except where it splits between D1 and D2, but we'll address that later.
KVL relates the voltages across the various elements:
$$ V_B = V_S + V_R + V_C + V_D $$
Capacitor C1 is initially discharged:
$$ V_C = 0V $$
Switch SW1 is closed, having zero resistance, and Ohm's law predicts the voltage across it:
$$ V_S = I \times 0\Omega = 0V $$
Resistor R1 will develop a voltage according to Ohm's law:
$$ V_R = I \times R_1 $$
A red LED passing current will develop about 1.7V:
$$ V_D = 1.7V $$
Plugging those values into the KVL equation will reveal initial voltage \$V_R\$ across R1, and the current \$I\$ through it:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_B &= V_S + V_R + V_C + V_D \\ \\
V_R &= V_B - V_C - V_S - V_D \\ \\
&= 9V - 0V - 0V - 1.7V \\ \\
&= 7.3V \\ \\
I &= \frac{V_R}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{7.3V}{2.2k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 3.3mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
This current is flowing downwards through C1, causing it to charge up, and \$V_C\$ will slowly rise. It eventually charges to 9V, but it will take time to get there. A simulation will show the rise of \$V_C\$ (the potential difference between nodes W and T in my schematic):

Resistor R1 started with a large voltage across it, and current was at a maximum of \$I=3.3mA\$. However, as the capacitor C1 charges, the voltage across it increases, and by consulting our KVL equation, it's clear that \$V_R\$ must be decreasing over time:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_B &= V_S + V_R + V_C + V_D \\ \\
V_C + V_R &= V_B - V_S - V_D \\ \\
&= 9V - 0V - 1.7V \\ \\
&= 7.3V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
The sum \$V_C + V_R\$ is constant (more or less; \$V_D\$ isn't always 1.7V, this value will drop as current nears zero), so if \$V_C\$ is rising, \$V_R\$ must be decreasing. Ohm's law tells us that current \$I\$ must also be decreasing:
$$ I = \frac{V_R}{R_1} $$
This is the decay of current \$I\$ over time:

Eventually current \$I\$ falls to zero, from its starting value of 3.3mA.

After a long time, then, the capacitor has charged to 9V, and the switch moves to position 2. The battery is effectively removed from the circuit, and the capacitor becomes the only voltage source present, a situation that looks like this:

simulate this circuit
In this configuration, the voltage across R1 has swapped polarity. Its right end now has the higher potential, due to the polarity of the new voltage source, capacitor C1. This is our new KVL equation:
$$ V_C = V_D + V_S + V_R $$
Initial current is calculated as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_R &= V_C - V_D - V_S \\ \\
&= 9V - 1.7V - 0V \\ \\
&= 7.3V \\ \\
I &= \frac{V_R}{R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{7.3V}{2.2k\Omega} \\ \\
&= 3.3mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Current starts at 3.3mA again, but this time it's in the opposite direction, upwards through C1. That capacitor is therefore discharging, with its voltage \$V_C\$ slowly falling towards zero over time:

The voltage across R1 is therefore also falling, as hinted at by the KVL equation, which shows that \$V_R\$ must decrease as \$V_C\$ falls:
$$ V_R = V_C - V_D - V_S $$
With \$V_R\$ falling, so does \$I\$. Eventually current drops to zero, and the situation settles at \$V_C=0V\$ and \$I=0A\$.


During both phases, charging (switch at 1)  and discharging (switch at 2), current started at 3.3mA, and fell to zero after some time. However, current direction was different during each phase. While C1 was charging, current was downwards through C1, lighting LED D1, and during discharge, current was upwards, illuminating D2.
Since current fell from 3.3mA to zero in each case, LED illumination would have appeared as a short pulse.

Very interesting... The rate at which the capacitor charges/discharges decreases towards the end of the process for two reasons: 1) the current-creating voltage decreases; 2) the "resistance" of the LED increases.
